# Docker Compose Pass Parameters

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There's option to pass command line parameters to the `docker-compose` so I can have more flexibility with docker compose file. But I have issue and it's not really clear why it happens. So here's the relevant docker compose 
files`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/mongodb/data/db:/data/db

  redis:
    image: redis:3
    restart: always

  application:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo:mongo
      - redis:redis
    restart: always
```

And another file `docker-deploy.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  application:
    image: myregistry.com:5000/myapplication:${APP_VERSION}
    links:
      - mongo:mongo
      - redis:redis
    restart: always
```

Now if I run command line `APP_VERSION=stage/1.1 docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-deploy.yml pull application` to pull the application image with a particular version it fails with output

```
Pulling application (myregistry:5000/myapplication:stage/1.1:latest)...
ERROR: invalid reference format
```

Note the `latest` added at the end. What's going on ? Where did it come from ?

Answer (score 0):

You want this to be:

`version: '2'

```
services:
  application:
  image: myregistry.com:5000/myapplication/${APP_VERSION}
  links:
   - mongo:mongo
   - redis:redis
  restart: always`
```

Note that I replaced the `:` with `/`

And also set your `APP_VERSION=stage:1.1`